# SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON string comprised of numerical values, but I keep getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected number**.

When I remove the preceding 0's it works, so I can get rid of the 0's easily enough, but I need the values formatted that way for display purposes, is there a simple way for me to parse this into an array of strings instead of an array of numbers?

Also, what would be the simplest way to remove all preceding 0's in the string? I am assuming a regex would be best? But any other suggestions are welcome.

```
JSON.parse('[26,27,28,29,30,31,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09]');
```

Comment: Removed tags from title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I added a solution to remove the zeros :). Check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the leading zeros. This works fine:

```
JSON.parse('[26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]');
```

JSON definition says integers must not have leading zeros

**EDIT** To remove the leading zeros:

```
var str = '[26,27,28,29,30,31,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09]';
str = str.replace(/\b0(\d)/g, "$1");
JSON.parse(str);
```

Cheers

Comment: De nada, q bueno q te haya servido ;)

Comment: Saludos, desde La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse('["26","27","28","29","30","31","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"]');
```

should parse it as an array of strings instead of array of numbers.